# Detect Flash player in web browser

Tags: flash

I'm now have a request to detect flash player version in client and if their version couldn't play so I will display something like "if you see this line is mean you need the flash player up to date to see this file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adobe Flash Detection Kit](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/) should do the trick for you.  Are you looking to do this with Flash (ActionScript) or in JavaScript?

Comment: I'm using javascript, and now I use detection kit it's worked! Thank you! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

If you use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to display your Flash (and you should), you can specify a minimum required version and an error message and it will handle detection for you.

Comment: This is the first time I'm using this so can you show me something helful, please. I need to display video file embed from youtube or from another url in firefox is done but not in IE. And I realize that because it's not has the lastest version to display this.

Comment: In that case you'll want to do some kind of Javascript browser detection (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) I can't give a specific example of using that for your purpose though. You could also do this detection on the server side.

Generally speaking, displaying different content to different browsers is a bad idea. Youtube embeds should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript to detect Flash Player
http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/how/shock/javaplugs/

Flash Player Detection Kit
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Flash Detection Library (Flash Detect)](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html)